# Grails render template unit test issue

Tags: unit-testing, templates, grails, render

I've got an action in my controller:

```
def dirtyMarker() {
    render(template: '/layouts/modals/marker/dirtyMarker')
}
```

and Id like to unit test it. Ive been trying lots of possibilities. This may seem simple, but nothing seems to work (Grails 2.2.3). I know that here, testing might not be important but Ive got lots of other methods that returns a rendered template and I dont know how to implement this test..

Comment: I miss the examples of what you have tried, and in what way it didn't work..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

seems to me that this should work:

```
void dirtyMarker() {
    controller.metaClass.render = { Map params ->
        assert params.template == '/layouts/modals/marker/dirtyMarker'
        return 'a'
    }

    def result = controller.dirtyMarker()

    assert result == 'a'
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks! I didn't assign the return value to a variable.. Ive been trying with "response" as default variable after render..

Answer (score 2):

You can also mock the template:

```
void testDirtyMarker() {
    views['/layouts/modals/marker/_dirtyMarker.gsp'] = 'mock contents'
    controller.dirtyMarker()
    assert response.text == 'mock contents'
}
```

See [Testing Template Rendering](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.3/guide/testing.html#unitTestingControllers) for details

Comment: It works, just make sure you've defined proper path to template

Comment: @MarcinMikołajczyk I guess you have omitted *.gsp :)